# Python server - error on launch

Tags: python, server

I' ve made a server using python:
Here it is the script:

```
import socket,threading

class ClientThread(threading.Thread): 
    def __init__(self, ip, port, clsock):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.ip = ip
        self.port = port
        self.clsock = clsock
    def run(self): 
        print ("Connection from : "+self.ip+":"+str(self.port))

        #----
        self.clsock.send("Welcome to the server")
        data = self.clsock.recv(2048)
        while 1:
            self.clsock.send(data+" "+data)
            data = self.clsock.recv(2048)
        #----

        print "Client disconnected..."

listathread = []
server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.bind(("192.168.0.14", 2837))
server_socket.listen(5)
while 1:
    server_socket.listen(5)
    print ("listening for connections...")
    (clientsock, (ip2, port2)) = server_socket.accept()
    newthread = ClientThread(ip2, port2, clientsock)
    newthread.run()
    listathread.append(newthread)
```

The problem is that when I launch this script using the Python Shell it works well but when I save it like a .py file and I launch it with the classic double-click the program gives me error and closes in a second!

I really don't understand what's appening!
Do you have any ideas to repair this problem ?

Comment: Open a command-line and type python <file>.py What error appears?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the way to solve my problem: I had to write the following code at the first line of my script :

```
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
```

So now I have :

```
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
import socket,threading

class ClientThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, ip, port, clsock):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

...code...
```